# OpenGL device coordinates shader behaves strangely

Tags: opengl, 3d, glsl, shader

I have an OpenGL application that is exhibiting behavior I do not understand. The application consists of a cuboid on a background and the cuboid is shaded according to where it is on the screen, using the following code:

The vertex shader:

```
#version 450 core

//In from VBO
in vec3 position;
in vec2 uv;
in vec3 normal;

//Out to Fragment Shader
out vec4 screenPos;
out vec4 fragPosition;
out vec2 fragUV;
out vec3 fragNormal;

//3D Uniforms
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    //Screen translation
    vec4 vertex = model * vec4(position, 1.0);

    gl_Position = projection * view * vertex;
    screenPos = projection * view * vertex;

    //Out to Fragment Shader
    fragPosition = vertex;
    fragUV = uv;
    fragNormal = normal;
}
```

The fragment shader:

```
#version 450 core

//From Vertex Shader
in vec4 screenPos;
in vec4 fragPosition;
in vec2 fragUV;
in vec3 fragNormal;

//To Target
out vec4 fragmentColor;

void main()
{
    fragmentColor = vec4(screenPos.x, screenPos.y, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

When I run this, I get a result that is clearly *inspired* by the screen position but does not behave as expected, as can be seen below. (The object of interest is the green/red/black cuboid in the foreground, the backdrop is behaving as expected).

[image: The problem]

That place where dark meets light should be in the center of the screen as that's where the device coordinates (which lie between -1 and 1 on both axises) transition from negative (no color) to positive (green and/or red color). However it's not, it's offset significantly from the center of the screen and the lines between negative and positive that should be vertical/horizontal do not appear to be. What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's going on is that you didn't provide normalized device coordinates. You provided *clip-space* coordinates. To get NDC space, you have to [divide the XYZ components of clip-space by the clip-space W](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Perspective_divide).

However, if you just want the position of the fragment, it's much easier to use [`gl_FragCoord` in the fragment shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader#System_inputs). It isn't normalized, but you can normalize it easily enough by providing a uniform that specifies [the viewport values](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Viewport_transform). Then just do a few math operations to normalize `gl_FragCoord`:

```
uniform vec2 viewportOffset;
uniform vec2 viewportSize;

vec2 NormalizePosition()
{
    vec2 temp = gl_FragCoord.xy - viewportOffset - (viewportSize/2);
    return temp * (2 / viewportSize);
}
```